# FFMPEG::Error on Uploading Video to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, linode

I am currently developing an app which involves uploading video to the server. The video is on .MOV format since it comes from an iOS Device. I have set-up FFMPEG on the server already. But everytime I try to upload a video, an FFMPEG error comes out:

FFMPEG::Error (Failed encoding.Errors: encoded file is invalid. Full output: ffmpeg version 2.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 26 2015 08:48:47 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/deploy/production/pinoymobiledirectory-ws/public/uploads/tmp/20151029-0424-12438-7062/tmpfile':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-10-29 04:24:11
  Duration: 00:00:05.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 784 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-29 04:24:11
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360, 715 kb/s, 30.11 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2015-10-29 04:24:11
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
[aac @ 0x143c980] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
):

lib/carrierwave/ffmpeg.rb:19:in `encode_video'
 app/controllers/v1/businesses_assets_controller.rb:33:in`upload_video'

Anyone who also got the same error as mine? How did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the message is 'The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it'.

You need to add this flag to your ffmpeg command. For example the following command, which will compress an mp4 video, contains this flag:

> ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -strict experimental -acodec aac CompressedBBB_320x180_aac.mp4

Comment: Worked for me. But I use https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg gem. So it's just `custom: %w(-strict -2)`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by installing the latest FFMPEG.
Followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917